# solr spell check not getting desired results

Tags: solr

I am having an issue in solr spell check set up, spell check is working fine but what problem i'm facing is result
i am searching for keyword 'coper' wrongly spelled but getting result 'cover' on top that is very confusing for me.
i'm not able understand why 'cover' showing on top in result set however 'copper' is also there ins result but it's showing below the 'cover';
I just want 'copper' keyword on the top in the result set.
below is the given query using search handler 'spell'

```
http://loalhost:8987/solr/apache-solr-catg1/spell?fl=*,score&wt=json&q=coper&rows=100&spellcheck=on&spellcheck.count=10&spellcheck.collate=true&spellcheck.collateExtendedResults=true&spellcheck.maxCollations=5&spellcheck.extendedResults=true&spellcheck.maxCollationTries=10&spellcheck.accuracy=0.5

below is configuration in solrconfig.xml

<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">

    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- Solr will use suggestions from both the 'default' spellchecker
           and from the 'wordbreak' spellchecker and combine them.
           collations (re-written queries) can include a combination of
           corrections from both spellcheckers -->
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">spellcheck_en</str>
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <!--<str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>-->
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
    </lst>
    
     <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
    
</requestHandler>

and the result given below
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":8},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"maxScore":0.0,"docs":[]
  },
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[
      "coper",{
        "numFound":10,
        "startOffset":0,
        "endOffset":5,
        "origFreq":0,
        "suggestion":[{
            "word":"cover",
            "freq":990},
          {
            "word":"co per",
            "freq":18},
          {
            "word":"copper",
            "freq":811},
          {
            "word":"cop er",
            "freq":5},
          {
            "word":"copier",
            "freq":48},
          {
            "word":"co pe r",
            "freq":138},
          {
            "word":"coder",
            "freq":6},
          {
            "word":"cop e r",
            "freq":110},
          {
            "word":"cooper",
            "freq":6},
          {
            "word":"c op er",
            "freq":87}]}],
    "correctlySpelled":false,
    "collations":[
      "collation",{
        "collationQuery":"cover",
        "hits":990,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections":[
          "coper","cover"]},
      "collation",{
        "collationQuery":"co per",
        "hits":24,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections":[
          "coper","co per"]},
      "collation",{
        "collationQuery":"copper",
        "hits":811,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections":[
          "coper","copper"]},
      "collation",{
        "collationQuery":"cop er",
        "hits":9,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections":[
          "coper","cop er"]},
      "collation",{
        "collationQuery":"copier",
        "hits":48,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections":[
          "coper","copier"]}]}}
          
I want 'copper' on the top in the result.
can anyone help please to rectify the issue.
```

Comment: Why do you expect `copper` to come above `cover`?

Comment: thanku for your valuable response
i think when i look for 'coper' then 'copper' is the most relevant keyword to 'coper' rather than 'cover'

Please clarify, it will be helpful for me

Comment: My point is that to be able to determine that something is "more relevant", there has to be a rule. What is the rule in your case? If you look at the output, the `cover` entry has more hits - so it could be assumed to be a more correct version. The edit distance (what's being used to suggest entries) is the same (I'm not aware of any support for changing the "cost" of each opreation) - one letter changed vs one letter removed. You could index a separate field with your rules applied instead, where identical letters gets merged into one - copper gets stored as coper - then use that for suggs

Comment: thanks again
but i don't have the idea as how to apply that rule to index a seprate field to merge the identical words.

could you please provide some code snippet which will be helpful for the implemenatation